# Conflicting dependency error when updating from Eclipse 3.7 to 3.7.1

Tags: 11.10, updates, eclipse

When i click on Check for updates, and select all, next, this is the error im getting.

I'm using a 64 bit ubuntu 11.10.

I'm not able to get PDT working either.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.M20110909-1335 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.1.M20110909-1335)
  Software currently installed: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Equinox Provisioning Operations API 2.1.0.v20110511-1821 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2.1.0.v20110511-1821)
    Equinox Provisioning Operations API 2.1.0.dist (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations 2.1.0.dist)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Shared profile 1.0.0.1317160468326 (SharedProfile_PlatformProfile 1.0.0.1317160468326)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations [2.1.0.dist]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Core Function 1.0.1.R37x_v20110906-8290FZ3FUqIcLqkVkEaTdn_14C7G (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.R37x_v20110906-8290FZ3FUqIcLqkVkEaTdn_14C7G)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations [2.1.0.v20110511-1821]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Equinox p2 Provisioning for IDEs. 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bj9JXOeQxOURYC-l9BL7rDEQO7 (org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group 2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bj9JXOeQxOURYC-l9BL7rDEQO7)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.R37x_v20110906-8290FZ3FUqIcLqkVkEaTdn_14C7G]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.M20110909-1335 (org.eclipse.platform.ide 3.7.1.M20110909-1335)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.user.ui.feature.group [2.1.2.R37x_v20110815-1155-6-Bj9JXOeQxOURYC-l9BL7rDEQO7]
```

Answer (score 1):

not an Equinox user, but would suggest that the problem here might be related to the correct version of Equinox which works with 3.7.1 of Eclipse as a cursory examination of the release downloads from the Equinox [downloads](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/) page is a bit confusing as to which version is the correct version to actually use with Eclipse 3.7.1.

Presume you would want to use a stable version, but the downloads section shows 3.7.x maintenance builds with odd release names (M2011....) and then 3.7 Stable builds with 3.8.x names, and then latest release builds with names more consistent with the current release numbers. This suggests that the problem is a dependency issue with the version loaded of the Equinox tools currently loaded into your version of Eclipse which are not compatible with the newer (updated) version of Eclipse.

This suggests that you may need to determine if the update to Eclipse requires a different version of Equinox, or if a reinstall of Equinox is required in order to update. You may wish to ask the Equinox community - not as familiar with this tool, but from what can be gathered, the version update will not resolve due to a dependency conflict which you can readily see. If Equinox can be removed and re-installed, that is probably the simplest method of updating.

HTH. Have a nice day. Wish there was more could advise, but Equinox is the issue, and not a regular user of same.